# Hybrid App automation using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Does selenium webdriver supports for Hybrid App(iOS & Android) automation?
If so what all the changes needs to be done in the capabilities?
Can we use appium server for hybrid app automation using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! Selenium Webdriver does supports Hydrid Apps automation.
Along with selenium libraries you will have to use java-client libraries,you can download it from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.appium%22%20AND%20a%3A%22java-client%22).
[Click here for Appium Tutorials](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?java#introduction) for reference.
Below is the desired capabilities to Automate Hybrid App.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilites = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilites.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");//Platform Version
capabilites.setCapability("platformName", "Android");//Platform Name
capabilites.setCapability("deviceName", "XXXXXX");//Specify Real Device id, you can get that from this command "adb devices"
//capabilites.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");//For emulator 
capabilites.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.gm");//Hybrid Application Package Name
capabilites.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.gm.ui.MailActivityGmail");//Hybrid Application Launchable Activity
capabilites.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.google.android.gm.ui.MailActivityGmail");//Hybrid Application Launchable Activity
capabilites.setCapability("newCommandTimeout",180);//Appium Server Time Out(3 min)
AndroidDriver driver =new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilites);
```